# Settings button with icon in Action Bar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar, action

As title says i don't know how to add button  to android action bar near title of app with icon.

I need to add it here as shown on picture 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njQwY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a menu resource, name it whatever you want.

Then, add this to your new .xml resource:

```
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:ignore="AlwaysShowAction">
    <item android:id="@+id/your_item_id"
        android:icon="@drawable/your_drawable_id"
        android:title="@string/your_string_id"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

The item tag defines the id, the icon and the title. the `showAsAction` defines if item is located at the action bar or submenu.

It's recommended to use string resources for your title, specially if you want to translate your app.

The menu icon is defined by your drawable resource. In order to use the correct size, I recommend to use the default icon asset wizard.

Add this to your `Activity` to add the menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu_name, menu);
    return true;
}
```

In order to detect menu pushes, use this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.your_item_id) {
        //Do your stuff here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

More info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: It doesnt work look.... 
 https://gyazo.com/4e6d06fc9317e0e7c08f44911086e546

Comment: Look here https://gyazo.com/4e6d06fc9317e0e7c08f44911086e546

Comment: Are you adding the code in a class that extends `Activity`?

Comment: I add code into MainActivity.class        here: https://gyazo.com/b0a21f47ccb22f1630d65de59b8603a2                              ,i added it after oncreate method

Comment: It seems all `R` are red, that's not good try to clean and rebuild your project. And I fixed a mistake I've made in my code. I forgot to include the `MenuItem` class.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/4e6d06fc9317e0e7c08f44911086e546  --- seems like it still doesnt work.. idk why R doesn't work really

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/374293fe405fbac6c753b21ad899ff5720180126200440/e8239a68239b4c6e4d66957c6d627cb920180126200440/7b2f67  HERE IS WHOLE PROJECT
could you take a look please ? :))

Comment: I restarted Android Studio , R problem gone , now i have problem only with
onCreateOptionsMenu  seems like android studio 3.0.1 don't have it??
and
onOptionsItemSelected seems like android studio 3.0.1 don't have it??
red "R" gone with restart of android but how will RED "item" gone ? 
Says this with code is not working..

https://gyazo.com/98c1bc72c04e2aaaa5b9d49f4872d1b9

Comment: EDIT : says Variable onCreateOptionsMenu is never used!
edit: Says Variable onOptionsItemSelected is never used!

Comment: Found error i put code at wrong place ... anyway thank you for your time , it works now!!

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, It's recommended to both upvote and accept.